# How do I change a Cocoa application's title bar color?

Tags: macos, cocoa, window

I need to change the application's title bar color in OS X. I would preferably like a solution involving Cocoa or Carbon, though I can do other venues if necessary. Essentially, a client of mine wants the title bar to be, say, black, as opposed to gray. I know this is possible as OS X's Reminders app does this, as does Firefox with personas and Google Chrome with themes.

I know that this has the potential of ruining the user experience, and I've considered other options, but this is the way the client wants it and I need to deliver. I can't really use a title-bar less window as the window is already designed and I'm sure that would kill the user experience a whole more than simply changing the window color would.

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Apple's Core Data Stickies sample app](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/serving-nsmanagedobjectcontext-over.html)

```
1. Create borderless window.

- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect 
                styleMask:(unsigned int)styleMask 
                  backing:(NSBackingStoreType)backingType 
                    defer:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (self = [super initWithContentRect:contentRect
                                styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask 
                                  backing:backingType 
                                    defer:flag]) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor yellowColor]];
        [self setHasShadow:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyWindow { return YES; }  

2. Place view on that window and implement custom title bar.
```

[image]
 **OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I **did** say that I can't use a title bar/border less window as the application window has already been designed. That is a neat way to do it, though. If I didn't need the regular OS X buttons I probably would do that.